# Was bedeutet: „Verflixt noch mal, da rührt sich was”?

Tags: meaning, phrase, colloquial

The little songs we had to listen to in German class seemed so silly at the time, but I can still recall a few of them all the way back to seventh grade. One was [Dracula Rock](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeFoERgv2gk)—but no YouTube in the stone age—that had a line even our teacher couldn't translate:

> Verflixt noch mal, da rührt sich was!

I understand this is somewhat dated usage and a colloquialism. How would a native English speaker express this thought?

Comment: "Verflixt" is to "verflucht" as "darn" is to "damn".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Verflixt noch mal" translated to English is something like "damn it". "Da rührt sich was" can be translated as "there's something moving".